# How to perform the Microsoft filename sorting in C/C++?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I have been successfully using the so-called "Windows sorting" in C# as illustrated below.

```
public class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "StrCmpLogicalW")]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogical(string x, string y);
}

private class NaturalSortComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        return NativeMethods.StrCmpLogical((string)a, (string)b);
    }
}
```

Coming from the Unix side, I know very little about the Microsoft flavor and variations of C++, so bear with me.

How do I sort some files in C++, using the above approach? In case it matters: I am NOT using MFC in this particular project.

My files are in a C++ `std::list` and I need to sort them as follows (or similar):

```
myFiles.sort();
```

Comment: why are you doing a PInvoke for this? [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) should do this for you.

Comment: Just write a comparison predicate based on `StrCmpLogical`, pass that to `sort`.

Comment: "why are you doing a PInvoke for this?" I need filenames that begin in `10.` to be placed after `9.` can the method yo suggest do that?

Comment: I think you'll find some answers if you search for the term "natural sort". For example, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127913/sorting-strings-is-much-harder-than-you-thought).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esteemed Self:

Here's the solution:

```
list<string> myFiles;
myFiles.push_back("10.somefilename.ext");
myFiles.push_back("9.somefilename.ext");
myFiles.sort(compare);
```

Additionally:

```
bool compare(const string& first, const string& second)
{
    wstring lhs = widen(first);
    wstring rhs = widen(second);
    bool ordered = StrCmpLogicalW(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str()) < 0;
    return ordered;
}
```

Finally:

```
wstring widen(string text)
{
    locale loc("");
    vector<wchar_t> buffer(text.size());
    use_facet< std::ctype<wchar_t> > (loc).widen(text.data(), text.data() + text.size(), &buffer[0]);
    return wstring(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
}
```

Your Self.

Comment: Can you iterate over the `myFiles` list prior to sorting and `widen` each string then, producing a `list<wstring>` that can just be sorted? It may be noticeably faster than widening during the compare, if you have any kind of large list (current algo may widen repeatedly).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of sort in C++ work like windows.

```
bool is_not_digit(char c)
{
    return !std::isdigit(c);
}

bool numeric_string_compare(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it1 = s1.begin(), it2 = s2.begin();
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.size() && i < s2.size(); i++)
    {
        if (std::isdigit(s1[i]) && std::isdigit(s2[i]))
        {
            it1 = std::find_if(s1.begin() + i, s1.end(), is_not_digit) - 1;
            it2 = std::find_if(s2.begin() + i, s2.end(), is_not_digit) - 1;
            j = it1 - s1.begin() < it2 - s2.begin() ? it1 - s1.begin() : it2 - s2.begin();

            int sm = 0;
            while (true)
            {


                if (*it1 < *it2)
                    sm = 1;
                else if (*it1 > *it2)
                    sm = 2;

                // both String number ended
                if (it1 == s1.begin() + i && it2 == s2.begin() + i)
                    if (sm != 0)
                        return (sm - 2);
                    else
                        break;
                // string 1 number ended
                if (it1 == s1.begin() + i)
                {// if string 1 number is'nt small then
                    if (sm != 1)
                    {
                        // Any non zero in string 2 number can make it bigger
                        do
                        {
                            it2--;
                            if (*it2 != '0')
                                return true;

                        } while (it2 != s2.begin() + i);
                        // if all was zeros then depends on sm
                        if (sm)
                            return false;
                        else break;
                    }
                    else
                        return true;
                }

                // string 2 number ended
                if (it2 == s2.begin() + i)
                {// if string 2 number is'nt small then
                    if (sm != 2)
                    {
                        // Any non zero in string 1 number can make it bigger
                        do
                        {
                            it1--;
                            if (*it1 != '0')
                                return false;
                        } while (it1 != s1.begin() + i);
                        // if all was zeros then depends on sm
                        if (sm)
                            return true;
                        else break;
                    }
                    else
                        return false;
                }

                it1--; it2--;
            }

            i = j;
            continue;
        }

        char a = s1[i], b = s2[i];
        if (a >= 'a' && a <= 'z')   a -= 'a' - 'A';
        if (b >= 'a' && b <= 'z')   b -= 'a' - 'A';

        else if (a < b)
            return true;
        else if (a > b)
            return false;
    }
    // shorter String wins
    if (s1.size() <= s2.size())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).